# Top bottom padding in case of absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

Why is it so when a paragraph is position absolutely the top bottom padding increases than the original? how to set it to the initial one? Thank you

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 pos { 
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;            
    background-color:red;
    color:yellow;
    }
</[![enter image description here][1]][1]script>
</head>
<body>

    <h3> practice page </h3>

    <div class="pos"> <p> paragraph tage </p> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: See MDN [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), it's not padding.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing a case of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) (not padding).

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the
>   margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
>   content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
>   margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child,
>   then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
>   parent.

This doesn't happen in the absolutely positioned example because:

> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

Comment: you are saying that its the margin of <div> tag adds to the margin of <p> tag which results in the increase of top bottom margin overall?

Comment: No, I'm saying when not absolutely positioned, the margin of the `<p>` collapses with the `<div> and ends up outside the `<div>. When positioned absolutely, no collapse occurs. Paragraphs have a margin by default in most browsers.

Comment: I reach to the point after applying some changes (<p> tag inside <div> tag) when properties are set through <div> tag top bottom margin increases and when directly applied on <p> tag there is no change in top bottom margin